# Example of JScience 5.0

Tags: java, units-of-measurement, jscience

I'm trying to give JScience-physics 5.0-SNAPSHOT a spin. Unfortunately I can't seem to find the entry into the code. The examples on the JScience website are all for 4.3.1; using the Amount class. From there it's pretty clear how to convert, doing maths, etc.

But there's no such a class in JScience-physics. First I thought it was a builder pattern starting from the unit instance, but no luck there either.

Does somebody in here already used this? If so, do you have an example on how to define amounts?

Comment: Why would somebody remove "TIA !!!" + my name from the bottom of the message ? As far as I know there's no etiquette against that. Or is there ? Anyway, it's not exactly friendly you know...

Comment: Signatures are strongly discouraged and *should* be edited out.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the 5.0 API is not finished yet: No amounts yet.

http://java.net/projects/jscience/lists/users/archive/2011-07/message/5

So no way to do actual math on quantities. Pity...